# Installing M2Crypto on CentOS

Tags: python, installation, m2crypto

I am trying to install M2Crypto on CentOS by compiling from the source. 
i am doing a python setup.py build
But I get the following error,

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
swig -python -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include -includeall -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
SWIG/_m2crypto.i:28: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslv.h'
SWIG/_evp.i:9: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
SWIG/_ec.i:7: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

Please advise ...

Prasanna

Comment: Why do you do it? m2crypto is packaged in RHEL 6. Which version of CentOS you have?

Answer (score 11):

The following should work:

```
env SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -D__`uname -m`__ -I/usr/include/openssl" python setup.py build
```

Edit: and `openssl-devel` package is of course also required.

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
swig -python -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include -includeall -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
SWIG/_m2crypto.i:28: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslv.h'
SWIG/_evp.i:9: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
SWIG/_ec.i:7: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'

Comment: I learn't that I had to use this command to complete the installation ... Also I was running this command as any another user ... make sure when u are installing stuff from source .. u should be logged in as root ..  Thanks a ton "abbot" for this command

Answer (score 7):

I just had this problem. In M2Crypto's INSTALL file:

```
Note about Fedora Core -based Distributions
----------------------------------------------------

Fedora Core (and RedHat, CentOS etc.) have made changes to OpenSSL
configuration compared to many other Linux distributions. If you can not
build M2Crypto normally, try the fedora_setup.sh script included with
M2Crypto sources.
```

My solution was to get the sources [from PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/M2Crypto/M2Crypto-0.21.1.tar.gz#md5=f93d8462ff7646397a9f77a2fe602d17) or from the [source](http://svn.osafoundation.org/viewvc/m2crypto/trunk/). Then in the M2Crypto directory:

```
$ chmod +x fedora_setup.py
$ ./fedora_setup.py install
```

If you're using a virtualenv, change the path of the python interpreter in that file, or activate your environment before building.

The only dependency that I had that wasn't satisfied on my system was `openssl-devel`.

Comment: fedora_setup.py or fedora_setup.sh?  The source I just downloaded (17-Sep-2012) has the .sh file, does not nave the .py file.

Comment: See if it says anything in INSTALL. Just follow the instructions in there.

Answer (score 3):

Install `openssl-devel`.

Comment: Let say you do:
$> updatedb&
$> locate openssl

Can you locate the missing headers on your system?

Comment: i have never used updatedb. I tried it though, it gives me an error, updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db' i have been using yum and rpm .. how can i find out the missing headers ?

Comment: Actually i had openssl installed and devel was missing ... Thanks Ignacio ..this suggestion solved a part of my problem

Comment: Does anyone know the corresponding Ubuntu package?

Comment: @JoeJ: I believe it's `libssl-dev`.

Comment: I have libssl-dev installed, but I'm still having problems.

Comment: @Seth  try this :  `DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu pip install "git+git://anonscm.debian.org/collab-maint/m2crypto.git@debian/0.21.1-3#egg=M2Crypto"`

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER!

Answer (score 0):

Follow Brian's instruction, and make sure you have install `openssl-devel`. if you experience error like this:

```
./fedora_setup.sh build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
swig -python -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include -includeall -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
SWIG/_evp.i:12: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf-i686.h'
SWIG/_ec.i:7: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf-i686.h'
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

You are running i386 operating system on 64 bit hardware. `arch =´uname -m´` will yields `i686`. The easiest way is to work around this is to create a symbolic link.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf-i386.h /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf-i686.h
```

Or if you experience errors like:

```
./fedora_setup.sh build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:27555: error: ‘Swig_var__evp_err_set’ undeclared (first use in this function)
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:27564: error: ‘Swig_var__dh_err_get’ undeclared (first use in this function)
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:27564: error: ‘Swig_var__dh_err_set’ undeclared (first use in this function)
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:27576: error: ‘Swig_var__rsa_err_get’ undeclared (first use in this function)
...
```

Some headers are missing, just issue the following command and try again:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem now (in 2018), I solved it by installing `openssl-devel`, `gcc` and `make`

`yum install gcc gcc-c++ make openssl-devel`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for RHEL 8.7 and will all probably work CentOS 8

```
pip install swig wheel M2Crypto
yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ make openssl-devel python3-devel
```