# Trouble pip installing M2Crypto on Centos

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, redhat, m2crypto

When I run `pip install M2Crypto`, I get:

```
/usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:31: Error: CPP #error ""This openssl-devel package does not work your architecture?"". Use the -cpperraswarn option to continue swig processing.

error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7855209/828584), but when trying to run the script with "build", I get

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: Permission denied
```

Is there a way to get around either error or another way to install M2Crypto?

Comment: Do you have the binutils package installed? What does `type -p as` say?

Comment: Etan, it's in /usr/bin, but I don't have execute permissions on it.

Comment: What are the permissions on it? What does `rpm -V binutils` say?

Comment: I don't have permission to execute rpm.. The permissions are at 700 for `as` and it's owned by root. I'm on a shared host, so I don't have root or sudo access.

Comment: You shouldn't need root or sudo to run that rpm command. That command doesn't modify anything. If you can't run crucial commands required to build a package then you are going to have a hard time building a package.

Answer (score 4):

I found another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4380239/289192

Try this command:

```
env SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -D__`uname -m`__ -I/usr/include/openssl" pip install M2Crypto
```